# How do I setup the date picker popup for date fields in a view?

Tags: 8, datetime, views

I setup a date field for my content type and also have an exposed date filter for my view, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the date picker popup to show up. Is there a setting that I have to set somewhere?

I've also installed Better Exposed Filters and I still don't see any option for my view. Also installed Date and the Calendar module. I know jQuery UI has a built in calendar popup and that's installed by default on Drupal 8 installs.

How do I turn this on?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the ui.datepicker wasn't added as a dependency in your theme as this isn't usually enabled by default in themes.

I use the seven theme for administration, so I had to add the line:

```
  - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Looks like this in my seven.libraries.yml file:

[image]

Comment: This is not strictly correct.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950 for a better explanation of what is going on.

Comment: So what did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. This simply doesn't work yet with just Drupal core.